# vim does not update screen right away

Tags: vim

I am using the cw (change word) command and the screen does not update until i press the ESC key. I have already set "slow" in my .vimrc.

Answer (score 1):

Are you seeing a $ show up at the end of your change region immediately, and then it goes away when you hit ESC? If so, try `:set cpo-=$`. You may also have to `:set nocp`.

Comment: Thanks! that kind of works. The entire word disappears. What would be nice is if the $ shows up and the letters appear immediately as I type.

Comment: That behavior, $ showing up and letters appearing immediately as you type, should be the behavior when you have $ in cpo. If you `:set cpo+=$` what, exactly, happens? BTW: the `slow` option does not exist in vim. It's a no-op option that exists only for backwards compatibility. See `:help missing-options`.

Comment: when cpo includes $, the $ shows up at the end of the word but the letters i type dont show up. The old word remains until I hit ESC when the word magically changes.

Comment: Hmmm... I've never seen that behavior in vim. What terminal are you using? You may want to try adjusting the ttyfast and term options to see if they change the behavior. If that doesn't work, and if you're using an older version you might want to try a newer one to see if maybe you're running into a (hopefully fixed) bug.

Comment: term=xterm. seems like a new enough vim. Version 7.2.79. Came with Jaunty on ubuntu.

Comment: What terminal program are you using (rxvt, eterm, gnome-terminal, konsole, xterm, something else...)? What happens in gvim? Do you see the same behavior? What about `vim -n NONE` (tells vim to ignore your .vimrc, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect the cw command to do?  Are you confusing it with dw (delete word)?

With cw, you should be doing:  **ESCcwFooBarESC**.  That will replace the current word your cursor is on with **FooBar** (the second ESC exits insert mode).

Comment: cw is Change word. For example if i place the cursor on the letter "C" of the word "Change" and type the command 'cw' I should then be able to type and see the letters I type replace the word "Change". vi works this way. vim does not seem to mimic this perfectly.